# Сортировка строк таблицы html по рейтингу

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день.

Есть админка галереи с рейтингом:

[image: Ссылка на фото галереи]

Душевных сил бороться с wordpress и допиливать сортировку из кучи совмещенных плагинов нет желания (устал от перепила админки). =)) Одна строка рейтинга лежит в tr с классом .iedit. Хотелось бы решить проблему jQuery.

Вопрос в том, как добраться до tr'ки, если я смотрю рейтинг глубоко в ней, и потом поменять местами tr, и возможно ли это? Или затея глупость и допиливать сортировку.

Структура html:

[image]

Comment: Возможно. [`jQuery.closest()`](http://jquery-docs.ru/traversing/closest/) позволит из ячейки получить её строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через closest можно получить tr текущий, вероятно, сортировать по индексам tr, например, а потом перестроить в нужном порядке. Я бы сделал так.

**UPD**
Ну, вот, например: http://jsfiddle.net/akwvcmvd/2/
В этом случае не снизу вверх идем, а от таблицы отталкиваясь. Вроде, вам ничего не должно мешать сделать так.

Comment: ПРимерчик пользования к моему ситуации, есть возможность набросать? Индексы присваивать tr'кам, и сортировку какуй функцией делать?(((

Comment: Обновил ответ.